# Formatting php array output

Tags: php, database, arrays

I need a little help with my PHP. Basically I have a field a page that I need the code to produce an outcome that looks like:

```
$existing_users=array('bra','vis','rfm');
```

Where it pulls the 'bra', 'vis', 'rfm' from the database.

So I figured cool lets make this into an array, and then explode it / separate it with '', Which I am not sure is the best approach, though I guess that's where my logic took me. And so I created the array

```
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM clients') or exit(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {$array[] = $row['shortcode'];}

print_r($array);
```

Which gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bra
    [1] => vis
    [2] => rfm
)
```

This is where I am stuck. I am not quite sure how to make things happen to my desired result. If anyone can provide me with advice I would be really appreciative.

Comment: what do you want to do with your result?

Comment: Whats the question? You access the array like `echo $array[1];` which will output `vis`, also stop using mysql_* functions and move to PDO or mysqli

Comment: Did you ever `print_r($existing_users);` ? It will print out exactly what you create from `MySQL`

Comment: Sorry if I didn't structure my question very well. @mimiEAM the end result I want is: $existing_users=array('bra','vis','rfm');

Comment: @MihaiIorga It wouldn't work as $existing_users is the end result that I want. I still need to push the data into the array from the database.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Cheers for the advice. Will research PDO & mysqli

Comment: but his does the job `$array[] = $row['shortcode'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the array before the while loop and you can push the values into it like

```
$existing_users = array();
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM clients') or exit(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {$existing_users[] = $row['shortcode'];}

print_r($existing_users);
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this ?

```
$existing_users=array($array[0],$array[1],$array[2]);
```

a raw way of doing what you want , you could use a loop and push the element on the new array if the return of your query is too big

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I thought of that, though that would also mean that there could only be three fields we would be looking at. The number of names I want to pull-in will be a variable depending on how many names are in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $user){
    $existing_users[] = $user;
}
```